# React retains local value inside method even after re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The below React code has a simple `useState` hook that updates the `newName` property. There is also a local variable `localPageTwoCount` that is incremented inside the `updateName` method.

```
import { useState } from "react";

function PageTwo() {

let [newName, setNewName] = useState("");
let localPageTwoCount = 0;

const updateName = () =>  {
    console.log("localPageTwoCount", localPageTwoCount)
    localPageTwoCount++;
    return setNewName("Name " + localPageTwoCount)
    
}

return <div>
    <h1>This content is from page2</h1>
    <div>newName {newName}</div>
    <div>localPageTwoCount {localPageTwoCount}</div>
    <button onClick={updateName}> Update Count </button>
    
</div>

}

export default PageTwo;
```

My understanding is that when `setName` is called it re-renders the component which re-initializes the variable `localPageTwoCount`, making `localPageTwoCount` always 0 in React.Dom. But the `localPageTwoCount` inside `updateName` method behaves weirdly it retains the incremented value and logs `localPageTwoCount 1` for every 2 clicks.

This is how the console looks

[image]

Can anyone explain how is this possible.

Comment: You might want to read about *[closures in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)*

Comment: @mandy8055 if its because of closure it should be on the first onClick but why it occurs on the second onClick and on third Click its again back to 0.

Comment: @mandy8055 its nither related to closures, nor strict mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to follow through the code to understand a bit.

In the first render:

`localPageTwoCount` is 0;
`newName` is ``.

When you click on the button, `updateName` is called:

```
// localPageTwoCount is logged as 0
localPageTwoCount++; //localPageTwoCount = 1;
setNewName("Name " + localPageTwoCount) // newName is set to Name 1 and triggers a rerender
```

The component rerenders because of state update. The value of `localPageTwoCount` becomes 0 again.

We click the button again and the method is called again. The same thing as above happens but since this time

`localPageTwoCount` is set to 0 and `updateName` is defined again.

```
// localPageTwoCount is logged as 0
localPageTwoCount++; //localPageTwoCount = 1;
setNewName("Name " + localPageTwoCount) // newName is set to Name 1 and triggers a rerender.
```

The answer lies here.
**Why** was there a rerender when the value was set to the same. This is because React could not figure out that there is no need for a rerender. This is documented [here](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update):

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects. (React uses the Object.is comparison algorithm.)

Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing expensive calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with useMemo.

But note that react does not go deep into the DOM tree. So which means that `Button` is not recreated on the DOM. Hence its event handlers remain the same.

The optimization can be seen here in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/great-einstein-mx66fv?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A28%2C1-30%2C1). I have added a log in the render body, and a log inside a `useEffect`.  Note that **yolo** inside `useEffect` is not logged the second time button is clicked.

If the event handlers are the same, then it still refers to the older `updateName`. The older `updateName` has the old closed over (closures) value of `localPageTwoCount` which had incremented to 1.

Now next time you click on the button:

```
localPageTwoCount++; //localPageTwoCount=2
return setNewName("Name " + localPageTwoCount); //sets newName to Name 2
```

And this time there is a valid re-render. And hence, `updateName` is recreated again with the new value of `localPageTwoCount` which is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use a variable, use `useRef` react hook

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";

function PageTwo() {

let [newName, setNewName] = useState("");
let localPageTwoCount = useRef(0);

const updateName = () =>  {
    console.log("localPageTwoCount", localPageTwoCount.current)
    localPageTwoCount.current = localPageTwoCount.current + 1;
    // You don't need to return anything from the onClick callback function
    setNewName("Name " + localPageTwoCount.current)
    
}

return <div>
    <h1>This content is from page2</h1>
    <div>newName {newName}</div>
    {/*This will show 0 unless there is re-render*/}
    <div>localPageTwoCount {localPageTwoCount.current}</div>
    <button onClick={updateName}> Update Count </button>
    
</div>

}

export default PageTwo;
```

`useRef` doesn't trigger a state change nor does it re-render the components. You can use the `useRef` hook to store data which doesn't require re-renders.

For more info go through react useRef [docs.](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef)

Working Demo: [React Playground](https://playcode.io/1744656)

Comment: I would like to know how/why it retains the localPageTwoCount value inside updateName method even after re-render.

Comment: useRef works the way useState, only difference is it doesn't trigger a re-render, which makes it perfect to be used to store data that are not required to be displayed.

You can go through the docs(https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef#referencing-a-value-with-a-ref) to understand more.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this behaviour , you need to understand how state works

there are two categories of datatypes : Primitive (number, string, boolean) , Non Primitive (array, object)

primitives are passed by value and non-primitives are passed by reference

now when you call setState and pass it new value , it checks if new value is same as current value or not

if its different value , it updates state and re renders component

if its same value , it wont update state and do not re render component

for non primitive types state will always update as it can not compare array or object with == comparison

but in primitive types, it can

so what is happening in your case is that

-> on initial render

localCount = 0
name = ""

when you click button , new value for name will be "Name 1" which is different from current value (""), so component will re renders and re initialises

-> after 1st click

localCount = 0;
name = "Name 1"

now when you click again , the new value for name will be "Name 1" which is same as current value("Name 1"), here react will not update state as both values are same so after 2nd click the function will not be re initialised and will have old closure value of localCount, so values will be

-> after 2nd click

localCount = 1;
name = "Name 1";

now when you click again , the new value for name will be "Name 2" which is different from current value("Name 1"), so now it will update state and every thing goes to its initial state back again

that's why every 3rd click you are getting increased value in console

to clearly understand it , try below example

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

const update = () => {
setCount(1);
}

useEffect(() => {
if(count === 0)return;
console.log("COUNT UPDATED")
}, [count])
```

here you will see that no matter how many times you call update() , you'll only see console once as state only updates if passed value is different from current value